# How can I make a regression in r where the dependent variable has different time values?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, correlation

I would like to create a regression where the dependent variable is the HHI and the independent variable is the organisational design of several companies. However, my data set is created so that I have 10 different variables for each of these, for each year (i.e. HHI_2000, HHI_2001,..)

I would like to do only one regression that takes into account all of them. Is that possible, or would I have to create a new model for every year?
This is what I did so far, for each year.

```
linearMod <- lm(HHI_2000 ~ org_d_2000 , data=data)
```

Below you can see a simplified example of my data

```
data <- structure(list(org_d_2000 = c(6, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
               org_d_2001 = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               org_d_2002 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0), 
               org_d_2003 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2),               
               HHI_2000 = c(500, 444.4, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
               HHI_2001 = c(330, 240, 280 , 380, 400, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               HHI_2002 = c(278, 140, 260 , 260, 350, 580, 700, 650, 0, 0),
               HHI_2003 = c(210, 90, 200 , 190, 300, 540, 780, 630, 500, 430),
               release_year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 
               2002, 2003, 2003)), 
          row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your code and maybe an example of what your desired output looks like?

Comment: I found the solution, I needed to use gather() in order to reshape my data from a wide to a long format